# Is there a way to place an image inside of a bokeh plot that uses categorical data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, bokeh, categorical-data

I am attempting to add a watermark to an existing categorial chart in bokeh.  I have tried to add the image via multiple methods, but haven't been able to get it to work yet.

I have tried using the category (string) as the x position value.  This leads to a WebDriverException:

> {"errorMessage":"undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'document.getElementsByClassName('bk-root')[0].children[0].getBoundingClientRect')","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"171","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:52857","User-Agent":"selenium/3.141.0
>   (python
>   windows)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":
>   \"\nreturn
>   document.getElementsByClassName('bk-root')[0].children[0].getBoundingClientRect()\n\",
>   \"args\": [], \"sessionId\":
>   \"308a7240-6123-11e9-a877-6d9cf99e3c61\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/308a7240-6123-11e9-a877-6d9cf99e3c61/execute"}}

I have also tried passing the category as the position in a list (category[5]).  This does not error out, but does not place an image on the plot.

```
# Add watermark
p.image_url(url=[r'static/images/image.png'], x='Mismatch', y=500, w=100, h=100,
                anchor = 'center',
                global_alpha = 0.2)
```

Expected result is that an image would appear on my categorical graph in the desired position.

The actual result is that no image appears, or a webdriverexception occurs.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this work-around with `Div`. You can place arbitrary HTML code inside a `Div` and position this `Div` anywhere on the screen using inline css stylesheets (Bokeh v1.1.0).

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Div, Row

p1 = figure(plot_width = 300, plot_height = 300, x_range = (0, 10), y_range = (0, 10), title = "Doggy as background")
p1.line([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 0], line_width = 5)
url = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/line/36/dog_head-512.png"
d1 = Div(text = '<div style="position: absolute; left:-300px; top:10px"><img src=' + url + ' style="width:280px; height:280px; opacity: 0.3"></div>')

show(Row(p1, d1))
```

Result:

[image]